# php - making calculations depending on game score

Tags: php, arrays

So i want to make some calculations depending on the score of a match. My code does what i want but it doesn't feel right, it feels like there should be a better way of doing this.

Already the scores in the keys of the array are something i have my doubts on ˆˆ, then i hardcode every possible score up until 10-10 which also doesn't look very effective and fast.

```
$score['0-0'] = someFunction($homeExp,0) * someFunction($awayExp,0) / 100; //10%
$score['0-1'] = someFunction($homeExp,0) * someFunction($awayExp,1) / 100; //10%
$score['0-2'] = someFunction($homeExp,0) * someFunction($awayExp,2) / 100; //etc..
$score['0-3'] = someFunction($homeExp,0) * someFunction($awayExp,3) / 100; //etc..
$score['0-4'] = someFunction($homeExp,0) * someFunction($awayExp,4) / 100;
$score['1-0'] = someFunction($homeExp,1) * someFunction($awayExp,0) / 100; //10%
$score['1-1'] = someFunction($homeExp,1) * someFunction($awayExp,1) / 100;
$score['1-2'] = someFunction($homeExp,1) * someFunction($awayExp,2) / 100;
$score['1-3'] = someFunction($homeExp,1) * someFunction($awayExp,3) / 100;
$score['1-4'] = someFunction($homeExp,1) * someFunction($awayExp,4) / 100;
$score['2-0'] = someFunction($homeExp,2) * someFunction($awayExp,0) / 100;
$score['2-1'] = someFunction($homeExp,2) * someFunction($awayExp,1) / 100;
$score['2-2'] = someFunction($homeExp,2) * someFunction($awayExp,2) / 100;
$score['2-3'] = someFunction($homeExp,2) * someFunction($awayExp,3) / 100;
$score['2-4'] = someFunction($homeExp,2) * someFunction($awayExp,4) / 100;
$score['3-0'] = someFunction($homeExp,3) * someFunction($awayExp,0) / 100;
$score['3-1'] = someFunction($homeExp,3) * someFunction($awayExp,1) / 100;
$score['3-2'] = someFunction($homeExp,3) * someFunction($awayExp,2) / 100;
$score['3-3'] = someFunction($homeExp,3) * someFunction($awayExp,3) / 100;
$score['3-4'] = someFunction($homeExp,3) * someFunction($awayExp,4) / 100;
$score['4-0'] = someFunction($homeExp,4) * someFunction($awayExp,0) / 100;
$score['4-1'] = someFunction($homeExp,4) * someFunction($awayExp,1) / 100;
$score['4-2'] = someFunction($homeExp,4) * someFunction($awayExp,2) / 100;
$score['4-3'] = someFunction($homeExp,4) * someFunction($awayExp,3) / 100;
$score['4-4'] = someFunction($homeExp,4) * someFunction($awayExp,4) / 100;
//up till about 10-10 

//all scores under 2 goals
$value = $score['0-0'] + $score['0-1'] + $score['1-0']; //30%

//all scores under 3 goals
$value = $score['0-0'] + $score['0-1'] + $score['0-2'] + $score['1-0'] + $score['1-1'] + $score['2-0']; //xx%

//all scores where home wins
$value = $score['1-0'] + $score['2-0'] ... etc etc ;
```

Is this the way to go? Or should i look into a different approach?

Comment: If your code works but you would like it to be reviewed/optimized, then CodeReview is a good place to post.

Comment: split the result in two variables (home and away) and parametrize your function. You will avoid all that awful mess of code

Comment: @mickmackusa he may not know of it, so here's the link to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: please comment your code with the task you are doing in each block of code

Comment: Frankly, this looks hideous. Why not just pass the two scores as parameters to `someFunction()`? Also, best had some [exception handling](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_exception.asp), because scores can go above 10 goals to one team and your array subscripting will turn into a fireworks display.

Comment: @mickmackusa I will next time, like Mawg says i didn't know about it but thanks for letting me know! Because of the answer provided here and my post limit i'll leave it here for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use two loops like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j <= 10; $j++) {
        $score[$i . '-' . $j] = someFunction($homeExp,$i) * someFunction($awayExp,$j) / 100;
    }
}
```

But the question you should really ask yourself is: Do you really need to calculate all this and put it in an array? And if you really need to, wouldn't an array of the form $score[4][3] be better?

Comment: Hi Fels, i'm not really sure if i have to...don't think so. How would you go about it? Or could you give me some advice about what to read up about to figure it out myself. Your code works btw :) Thanks for that!

Comment: For the array: Instead of using $score[$i . '-' . $j], you can use a two dimentional array: $score[$i][$j] = someFunction($homeExp,$i) * someFunction($awayExp,$j) / 100;


Then to read it you can use something like $test = $score[0][2];